# directive to convert decimal value to integer

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a directive to convert `numeric` value into `integer`.

For example, I have input type number and when user types 1.1 this value should be converted back to 1.

```
app.directive('toInteger', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                var value = parseInt(value);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Where am I wrong?

**Problem:**
If i enter `1.1` than directive converts it back `1`. However, it keeps on showing `1.1` on view (inside input field).

I am using directive with my html as follow

```
<input type="number" name="input" class="form-control" min="0" max="1000" data-ng-model="input" to-integer>
```

Comment: what's the problem ?? it's don't convert or value is missing ?

Comment: Are you adding the directive to your input element?

Comment: Why do you have a `var value` shadowing the argument `value`? What happens when you drop the shadowing and instead say `var intvalue = patseInt(value); return intvalue`

Comment: you should probably set a formatter as well https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your **directive**, its working fine as per your requirement. Please use this

```
app.directive('toInteger', function ($parse) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            var value = parseInt(value);
            $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, value);
            scope.$apply();

        });
    }
};});
```

Comment: Thanks , i shall check it and let you know the outcome.